# Django Custom Authentication authenticating users incorrectly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

So I am trying to build a website using Django where there are two separate user bases, one is `user` and the other is `agent`. Now I imported `User` from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and have a separate model for `Agent`. Now the problem is, when I enter `user` credentials into `agent sign in` page, it is logging me in as an `agent` even though it is a user instance and returning error `'User' object has no attribute 'slug'` because there is no `slug` in user model. Same is happening when I use `agent` credentials in the `user sign in` page. It is logging me in as a `user` even though there is a separate authentication `backend` for `agents`. `Incorrect credentials` are being shown when incorrect credentials are provided but somehow agent credentials in user sign in are not incorrect credentials and vice versa. How can I fix this?

My models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Agent(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)
        self.save()
 

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

My forms.py:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class AgentRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    image = forms.ImageField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        fields = ['username', 'name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        agent = super(AgentRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        agent.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            agent.save()
        return agent
    

class AgentSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

My backends.py:

```
class AgentBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            agent = Agent.objects.get(username=username)
            if check_password(password, agent.password):
                return agent
        except Agent.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

My views.py:

```
def agent_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AgentSignInForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            agent = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if agent is not None and agent.is_active:
                login(request, agent)
                messages.info(request, f"Welcome Agent {username}.")
                return redirect("agent-dashboard", agent.slug)
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
    form = AgentSignInForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="users/agent_login.html", context={"form":form})

    
class AgentDashboard(DetailView):
    model = Agent
    template_name = 'users/agent_dashboard.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        agent = self.get_object()
        properties = Property.objects.filter(agent=agent)
        context['properties'] = properties
        return context
```

My settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "users.backends.AgentBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
]
```